# `Identifiable` conformance return type generic as variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

#### Background:

I'm trying to build an `OutlineGroup` from this example from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup

But instead of using static types I want to use objects that conform to my protocol. So the question is more general if that's possible in swift what I'm trying to do:

#### Problem:

I have protocol that gives me people `coworkers` and `name` from various objects:

```swift
protocol CastProtocol {
    var name: String { get }
    var coworkers: [CastProtocol]? { get } // here will be the build error later
}
```

And consider two models as example:

```swift
class Actor: Identifiable, CastProtocol {
    var id: Self { self }
    var name: String { return "Chuck Norris" }
    
    var coworkers: [CastProtocol]? {
        return [
            Director()
        ]
    }
}

class Director: Identifiable, CastProtocol {
    var id: Self { self }
    var name: String { return "Gina Carey" }
    
    var coworkers: [CastProtocol]? {
        return [
            Actor(),
            Director(),
            Actor()
        ]
    }
}
```

So till now everything working, but I need to ensure that my `CastProtocol` conforms to `Identifiable`, so changing my protocol implementation to:

```swift
protocol CastProtocol: Identifiable {
    ...
}
```

And now this creates a problem:

> Protocol 'CastProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

#### Questions:

1. So there is a way to do this with return not static type in `coworkers` or maybe I should go with subclassing?
2. Is that a correct approach? Maybe the only thing I'm missing is declare in protocol level identifier requirements for identifiable? But if so - how to do it?
3. I cannot really go with associatedType I think. If `coworkers` in this example can contain `Actor` or `Director` associatedType I think cannot be use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protocols never conform to other protocols. The syntax `protocol CastProtocol: Identifiable` does not mean "CastProtocol conforms to Identifiable." It means "in order to conform to CastProtocol, a type must also conform to Identifiable."

To the question, though, no, you cannot require that. `Identifiable` includes an associated type `ID`. Consider this code:

```
let coworker in coworkers {
    let id = coworker.id // What type is `id` here?
    ...
}
```

Swift cannot assign a single type type `id` in this case. Someday they may add a feature called a Generalized Existential that would allow `id` to be inferred to be the type `Any where Self: Hashable`, but it's not currently possible to express that in Swift.

But in your case, it couldn't work anyway. Say you could do this. Since you've made the identifier be the object itself, eventually the system would need to evaluate `Director == Actor`. That's not possible in Swift. Those aren't the same type.

Instead, I suspect you want this, if you really want Cast members to be classes:

```
protocol CastMember: class {
    var name: String { get }
    var coworkers: [CastMember] { get } // Optional Arrays are almost always wrong
    var id: ObjectIdentifer { get }
}

extension CastMember {
    var id: ObjectIdentifier { ObjectIdentifier(self) }
}

// You can still put Identifiable here for [Actor] properties
class Actor: CastProtocol, Identifiable {
    // ...
}
```

Now, this won't let you put these directly into a `ForEach(actor.coworkers)` call, which I assume is what you want. Personally, I'd just pass the `id: \.id` parameter, but you can of course make it a little nicer with an extension if you do this a lot:

```
extension ForEach where Content : View, Data.Element == CastMember {
    public init(_ data: Data, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content) {
        self.init(data, id: \.id, content: content)
    }
}
```

Note the `Data.Element == CastMember` not `:`. This applies when it's an array of CastMember, not an array of things that conform to CastMember.

Comment: Wow, thanks for detailed answer! really appreciate it! Now I get why `==` is not possible, thanks! One followup question for a comment: ` Optional Arrays are almost always wrong` - what do you mean by that? I'm following this example for OutlineGroup: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup and the optional array is used there to show content or "dropdown". And actually want to user it in initializer for OutlineGroup from KeyPath, but it's more like for each so will try to made the extension you wrote works for OutlineGroup

Comment: Ah, it can make sense for an outline if you want to distinguish between "missing" and "empty." If you can have something that is expandable, but has no elements, then yes, optional array is correct. That's just really rare and I didn't focus on the use of OutlineGroup. You can tell if you're doing it right by whether you feel the need to write. `?? []`. If need that, then you almost certainly didn't mean optional, you just meant empty. But if you have specific `== nil` tests, then you probably really did mean optional.

Comment: The classic time I know someone is misusing optional array is when they ask "how do I write an `emptyOrNil()` extension?" If you feel the need to write a special extension because you're doing this so often, you *know* you're using optional array incorrectly :D

Comment: Great, thanks! eveything clear and it's working - with Outline it's even without extra init needed since there is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup/init(_:id:children:content:)-2ujiu initializer with keyPath for identifier. Thanks!